# Replace \" with " in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, replaceall

I have a JSON from my web server that I obtain from a XMLHttpRequest.
The data has the following form when I print it out using

```
var data = this.responseText;
console.log("data=" + JSON.stringify(data));

data=[{\"day\":0,\"periods\":[\"0xffffffffffff\"]}]
```

I process the JSON using jquery but I'm getting an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in `[{"day":0,"periods":["0xffffffffffff"]}]`

I'm assuming the problem is due to the escaping of the quotes as if I hard code data to `[{"day":0,"periods":["0xffffffffffff"]}]`
I don't get the error.

I've tried various ways of getting rid of the escape but without success:

```
data = data.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

Does not modify the string at all;
I found a function from another thread, replaceAll, but this:

```
var newData = data.replaceAll("\\","");
```

..made no difference either.

Trying to replace \" with ' then replacing the ' with " just returns me to \"

```
var newData = data.replaceAll("\"","'");

now newData = [{'day':0,'periods':['0xffffffffffff']}]

newData = newData.replaceAll("'","\"");

and it's back to [{\"day\":0,\"periods\":[\"0xffffffffffff\"]}]

Trying to process with single quote, i.e. [{'day':0,'periods':['0xffffffffffff']}] gives me the same Uncaught TypeError message.
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `/\/` would be the same as `//` since \ is an escape. Try `/\\/`. But best thing would be to fix the server giving invalid JSON out. Or is the problem that you’re trying to stringify the data when you should be parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you are using `JSON.stringify` on a string. Have an exact look on `this.responseText` - response**Text** - that you are using as property. Just change it to

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
console.log("data=" + data);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. The JSON now gets correctly processed.